# Media Player project, lock screen WP7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I'm doing simple media player with Media Player class, and I have some problems. When I locked up the screen while my music plays, and then unlock it, music stops. How to fix this ?

Comment: The Current State after unlocking is Playing but player isn't works :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enable the application to lock under lockscreen by disabling the idle detection

```
PhoneApplicationService.Current.ApplicationIdleDetectionMode = IdleDetectionMode.Disabled;
```

A better way would be to use the background audio agent (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202978(v=vs.92).aspx)

Comment: mhm, I'm doing this, and app runs in foreground. But when i unlock the screen stops.